# How to recover data from drives in bcache configuration

Tags: raid, btrfs, cache, bcache

I'm trying to recover the data in hard drives that was set up in raid and bcache.

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and just migrate the two hard drives in raid 1 to another computer.

I have no longer the ssd that I was using as Cache with bcache.

The drives in a raid 1 was set up using mdadm and this raid has a ssd partition cache using `make-bcache -B /dev/md0 -C /dev/sdd3`

How can now get the data out of the dives ?

I try to make the bcache again but only with the raid draives (/dev/md0) but i can not mount it.

The filesystem that i used was btfs.

I'm happy to describe more if it is necessary.
Thanks

Comment: With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that seems to be posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed, so it's possible they'll already be gone by the time you check back in here. In that case, you'll just be thoroughly confused on what I'm talking about ;-).

Answer (score 1):

find the start sector of real filesystem by `bcache-super-show /dev/md0`, check output of `dev.data.first_sector`，e.g. 16

find out the sector size by `fdisk -l /dev/md0`, check the line looks like `Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes`, this means the sector size is `512 bytes`

mount the real filesystem with offset (16 * 512 = 8192 bytes):
`mount -o loop,offset=8192 /dev/md0 /mnt`

also you can specify this option via `/etc/fstab` to mount it on startup.